# htaccess redirect with multiple parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using following htaccess rewrite for clean URL:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ subcategory.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ item.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&item=$3 [L,QSA]
```

And I get clean URL like:-  domain.com/SHOE/MEN/ITEM-NAME

Now I want change URL to be:-  1. domain.com/BOOTS/MEN/ITEM-NAME
and similar changes at parent level like: 2. domain.com/BOOTS/MEN and 3. domain.com/BOOTS

I tried with one additional line

```
RewriteRule ^SHOE/.*$ /BOOTS/$1 [L,R]
```

But still not working. Sorry If I made it complex. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, sorry. Please take the time to revise your question. There is an `edit` link below it for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, but I *assume* you want to redirect incoming browser requests to URLs using `BOOTS` instead of `SHOE`, whilst keeping the rest of the requested URL as it is...

For that try something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?SHOE(.*)$ /BOOTS$1 [R=301,END]
```

That rule should be placed at the beginning of a possible series of rewrite rules. If you are using an old apache http server you might have to use the `L` flag instead of `END`. That also means you might have to take additional measures to prevent an endless rewriting loop.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files ("`.htaccess`"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for reply Arkascha. Sorry for unclear question. Yes you are right. I want SHOE to be replaced with BOOTS but remain rest of URL after BOOTS same. I tried your solution but it says: "Internal Server Error".

Comment: @Sunil As always with an http status 500 take a look into your http servers error log file to learn what the actual issue is. Most likely it is what I referred to with mentioning an old version of the apache http server: have a try replacing the `END` flag with an `L` flag.